# Android:Robospice setup

Tags: java, android, eclipse, github, robospice

I'm developing a new android down-loader and i want to use [ROBOSPICE](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Setup-for-Non-Maven-users) in my project but really i don't know how to setup it. I think there must be a jar file to attach to my project and start using its classes but there is nothing like that on the internet.
I also tried to get a [ROBOSPICE](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Setup-for-Non-Maven-users) clone from git but i found that all classes in the cloned project where 'tests' not the core code.
Please help...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No jar file is needed. just add the the following dependency in your `Build.Gradle` (module) file

```
compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-spring-android:1.4.14'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.14'
```

If your are getting error on DuplicateEntry, add this also,

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```

inside

```
android {
}
```